# Почему иногда не удается найти html-узел (HTMLAgilityPack)?

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    doc.LoadHtml(item);

    string title=null;
    string cost= null;

    var titleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'title-info-title-text')]");
    if (titleNode != null)
        title = titleNode.InnerText;

    var costNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'js-item-price')]");
    if(costNode!=null)
        cost = costNode.GetAttributeValue("content", "0");
```

Этот код выполняется в нескольких потоках и обычно все нормально. Но иногда SelectSingleNode возвращает null. Я ставил брейк-поинт и проверял в ручную. Нужный тег был. 
Ощущение, что doc.LoadHtml() - работает асинхронно, и периодически не успевает загрузить страницу. Или это моя оперативная память отъезжает?

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Возможно, содержимое сайта динамически подгружается с помощью JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала загружать html например с помощью `WebClient`, а потом уже скармливать его `HtmlDocument`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);
```

Если все еще будут проблемы, можно пытаться повторять загрузку в цикле несколько раз. Пример кода [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910829/external-web-page-is-not-loading-everytime-in-htmlagility-pack)